# Scheduled Jobs Time Zone

Tags: scheduled-job

When scheduling a run date for a scheduled Job, which timezone should I use?
Same question regarding CiviRule Delays... Which timezone is it taking into consideration?

When I view the Job Log, I see that things are recorded in UTC time...

Using CiviCRM 4.7.27 with Drupal 7